# How to debug hibernate issue?

Tags: hibernate

When I hibernate my Ubuntu 20.04, most of the time it works, but sometimes it just hangs there.

How can I know what is causing the issue? I am using a laptop

Comment: Is your Swap file as large as your RAM?

Comment: Yes, it is larger

Comment: I have increased the swap partition since originally it is only a little bit larger than my RAM. I will see whether that works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have 32G of RAM and a 40GB swap partition, using LUKS + LVM. It just hangs, the mouse disappearts, the screen freezes (with all the windows still apparently open) when I try `sudo pm-hibernate`. `sudo systemctl hibernate` fails with an error claiming my swap partition is not large enough.